# how to send data through javascript using url?

Tags: dropdownbox

This is the code of my script part. can any one guide me

```
update_selected: function() {
    var url = base_url + "event/update_selected_event/" + this.id /+ this.event_id;
    window.location.href = url;

}
```

Comment: window.location.href will redirect you to that url. Are you asking how to pass information to that page? url parameters would do that for you.

Comment: ya..i want to send id and event_id in function update_selected_event that is in event controller..so how can i pass id and  event id??

Comment: got it - answer added.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the what your script is trying to do. Since you are causing a redirect with this line

```
window.location.href = url;
```

I am guessing you want to pass information to the page you will navigate to. For this you can use URL parameters

```
var url = base_url 
    + "event/update_selected_event" 
    + "?id=" + this.id
    + "&event_id=this.event_id";
```